# How to compile .py to .exe with modules unsupported by pyinstaller?

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

I want to compile my script to .exe but there are some modules that pyinstaller dont support, what can i do?

I also tryed py2exe but it doesn't worked

Comment: What's the module?

Comment: Pynput and praw

Comment: I don't know about `praw`,but `pynput` can be used in pyinstaller.